# Identifying Issues with Service Worker Informing Users of New Version of React App

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, auto-update

A former colleague created an auto-update mechanism to inform users when a new version of our app is available.  It appears he based it on examples like these:

- https://betterprogramming.pub/prompting-new-app-versions-with-the-service-worker-and-create-react-app-bf3350d3bed1
- https://dev.to/daniellycosta/showing-new-version-available-notification-on-create-react-app-pwas-3jc9

Our implementation displays a tiny modal with a `RELOAD` option and a `Do it later` option.  Assuming the user clicks on `RELOAD`, that appears to load the new version of our app.

On my computer, it seems to appear regularly when we have a new version.  But some of our users are periodically reporting that the tiny modal does not appear.  I've examined the code and it appears to be inline with the aforementioned examples.

I'm curious if anyone else has experienced this periodic flakiness and, if so, how did you fix it?